# WP_Query sort by meta_value_num or date

Tags: posts, wp-query, custom-field, post-meta, order

I am using `meta_value_num` to sort posts by price and allow users to use a dropdown to change between max and min. What I need now is the ability to select from `Min Price` or `Max Price` or `Newest Posted` or `Oldest Posted` Is it possible to sort by multiple values?

**WP Query**

```
$args = array(
            'order' => $_POST['date'],
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num date',
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'meta_key' => 'ek-product-price',
);
```

**Form**

```
            <select id="select1" type="text" name="date">
                <!-- FIRST 2 OPTIONS FOR SORT BY PRICE META VALUE -->
                <option value="ASC" type="hidden">ASC</option>
                <option value="DESC" type="hidden">DESC</option>
                <!-- ADD IN OPTION FOR SORT BY DATE ADDED -->
            </select>
```

Comment: You want to give options to sort by (Min Price OR Max Price OR Newest Posted OR Oldest Posted) or (Min Price AND Max Price AND Newest Posted AND Oldest Posted)?

Comment: @Annapurna all `OR` so either sort by min OR max price OR new OR oldest dates.

Comment: why not do the same thing you're already doing with the `order` parameter? add another form field to choose what to order by.

Comment: @Milo id rather keep it to the same select field for ease of use, good idea though!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking then. How does one select what to order by?

Comment: @milo So the user would sort by either: Newest first or Oldest first or by highest price (meta) or lowest price (meta). For example like this - http://tinyurl.com/ju5ee8p then click the 'Sort by' dropdown.

Comment: @Milo Worked it out with a different approach below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the following method. There's probably a better way to do it but this is good enough for it's purpose.

**Added `IF` statement for options**

```
if($_POST['date'] === 'HIGH'){
    $order = 'meta_value_num';
    $sort = 'DESC';
}
elseif ($_POST['date'] === 'LOW'){
    $order = 'meta_value_num';
    $sort = 'ASC';
}
elseif ($_POST['date'] === 'ASC'){
    $order = 'date';
    $sort = 'ASC';
}
elseif ($_POST['date'] === 'DESC'){
    $order = 'date';
    $sort = 'DESC';
}
```

**Then inside the $args**

```
$args = array(
    'order' => $sort,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => 'ek-product-price',
    'orderby' => $order,
)
```

**Form**

```
<select id="select1" type="text" name="date">
  <option value="ASC" type="hidden">ASC</option>
  <option value="DESC" type="hidden">DESC</option>
  <option value="HIGH" type="hidden">HIGH</option>
  <option value="LOW" type="hidden">LOW</option>
</select>
```